# Which one will block first? tcp-wrapper or Iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables, firewall, tcp-wrappers

If a service (or port) is blocked in both `TCPwrapper` and `Iptables`, which will block the request first and why?

Comment: IPtables.  TCPwrappers come into play only after the TCP connection has been established; it can close connections, but it can't prevent them from being opened.

Comment: e.g. tcpwrappers are a construct only established at app level in user land.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Answer:**
Its Iptable(firewall).

**Why?**

In simple words, TCPwrapper comes in between firewall and network Services.

In the OSI model, the TCPwrapper works in **Application layer** while iptable works mostly in **Transport layer**.

Source:: [Access Control Using TCP-wrappers](http://www.slashroot.in/linux-access-control-using-tcp-wrappers)

Answer (score 1):

iptables (netfilter) is kernelspace, tcp wrappers are userspace.

Comment: That's true, but it doesn't have any bearing on the question.